# how to start a animtion onclick and on button click go further?

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, onclick, css-animations

I want to start a animtion on click of a div and after the animtion is done it just keeps it position. I fixed the anitmtion that i works on reloading the page but didnt fix it for onclick do you guys have an idea??

.tsx file:

```
import styles from "./WaterTracker.module.css";

export default function WaterTracker() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div className={styles.mainContent}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

.css file :

```
:root {
    --background: #f8f8f8;
    --dark: #303032;
}

.mainContainer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
}

.wrapper {
    background: var(--background);
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.mainContent {
    position: relative;
    background: var(--dark);
    border: 0.25em solid var(--dark);
    height:8rem;
    width: 8rem;
    outline: 0.25;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.mainContent::before {
    content: "Drink je water";
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.mainContent::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: var(--background);
    height: 200%;
    width: 200%;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    border-radius: 45%;
    animation: spin 6s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(500deg);
    }
}
```

I hope that when this works i also can change the tranlateY from -100% to any number with a button so the animtion will first go to -50% and when i click on the button to -100% if you guys have a fix for this as whel it would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ionic's Animation. Check out the docs for examples. https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations